# How to navigate from a screen of the BottomNavigationBar to another screen but still in the same icon in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, bottomnavigationview

I'm using `BottomNavigationBar` in my app and I built it successfully , I have 3 icons and each one has a screen (the default functionality of `BottomNavigationBar`) . But if I'm in the first screen , I want to navigate to another screen but still in the first icon in `BottomNavigationBar` .

I tried to navigate from first screen to another but the `BottomNavigationBar` gone because it launches a new screen and I want to stay in the same index of the `BottomNavigationBar`

How to navigate to another screen in the same index of the `BottomNavigationBar`

suppose screen A is in index 0 .. I want to navigate to screen B from screen A in the same page(same index) of the navbar

here is my code of the `MainPage`

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
   const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
 }

 class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int currentIndex=0;
  final screens = [
      Home(),Home(),Home()
  ];
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
         backgroundColor: Color(0xfffbfbfb),
         currentIndex: currentIndex,
         selectedItemColor: Color(0xff5bc0de),
         unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
         type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
         onTap: (index)=>setState(() {
           currentIndex=index;
         }),
         items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset("assets/home.png"),label: "Home",),
           BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset("assets/meeting.png"),label: "Schedule",),
           BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset("assets/notification.png"),label: "Alert",)

         ],
       ),
       body: SafeArea(child: screens[currentIndex])
     );
   }
 }
```

And here is how I navigate to another screen

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width:800,
        height: 800,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Center(
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Second()));
            },
            child: Text("helllo"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can't change the structure of the app, use state management (e.g., provider, riverpod, bloc) to track the index of the navbar even on other screens.

Comment: Suppose I use Provider , what will I do with the index of the navbar ?

Comment: you could remove `int currentIndex=0;` and replace it with the one from provider

Comment: I don't want to change the index , I want to change the screen if index 0 for example .. suppose screen A is for index 0 .. I want to navigate to screen B from screen A in the same page of the navbar